# What is the shortcut to select everything between curly braces in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, selection, code

Is there any shortcut in Notepad++ to select all (highlight) codes between the curly braces (start & end)?

E.g. Code between if-else, nethod definition, while, for loop etc.

Comment: SynWrite editor, also free, has such a command: `Search > Select brackers`.

Comment: if you want to jump between braces use Ctrl + B

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> does that
(shows in “Search” drop down also).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any shortcut in Notepad++ that could do what you are trying to achieve but you could record a macro and assign a keyboard shortcut to it:

1. in the 'Macro' menu click '*Start Recording*'
2. press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
3. in 'Find what' give the following Regular Expression: `(?<=\{)[^}]+(?=\})`
   (this will find and select all text between 2 matching curly brackets)
4. make sure that you tick 'Regular Expression' under 'Search Mode'
5. click '*Find Next*'
6. in the 'Macro' menu click '*Stop Recording*', then '*Save Current Recorded Macro...*'

During the last step there is the option to assign a keyboard shortcut for this macro.